# How do I use SQL to check whether a record exists?

Tags: sql, select, join, null, exists

I have an SQL table for employee records called HRRM. This table has fields such as employeeID, FirstName, LastName.

There is another table in SQL called HREC. This table is joined to the HRRM and contains emergency contact details.

Basically, each employee in HRRM can have many emergency contacts in HREC.

How do I select all employees from HRRM that do not have any records in HREC?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I select all employees from `HRRM` that do not have any records in `HREC`?

This English statement translates to SQL almost word-for-word:

```
SELECT *
FROM HRRM e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM HREC r WHERE r.emp_id=e.emp_id)
```

A less trivial way is using an outer `JOIN`:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM HRRM e
LEFT OUTER JOIN HREC r ON r.emp_id=e.emp_id
WHERE r.emp_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

use NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT * FROM HRRM R 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM HREC E WHERE R.EMP_ID=E.EMP_ID)
```

should not use join except you use DISTINCT at the same time